# Window resize set variable in controller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In Angular, I'm watching for the window size and changing the 'device' variable on the controller if the widow width crosses a certain threshold:

```
 var myModule = angular.module("MyApp", [])
    .controller('MyController', function(UseHttp){

       // store reference of "this"
       var self = this;

       function setDevice(){
          var wWidth = $(window).width();
          var theDevice;

          if (wWidth <= 991 && wWidth > 767) {
            theDevice = "narrow desktop";
          } else if (wWidth <= 767 && wWidth > 620) {
            theDevice = "iPad";
          } else if (wWidth <= 620 && wWidth > 500) {
            theDevice = "largeMobile";
          } else if (wWidth <= 500 && wWidth > 320) {
            theDevice = "mediumMobile";
          } else if (wWidth <= 320) {
            theDevice = "smallMobile";
          } else {
            theDevice = "desktop";
          }

          self.device = theDevice;          
      }

      //self.device gets set on window resize
      $(window).resize(function(){
        setDevice();
        $scope.$apply(); //but where do I store the var $scope?
      });

      //self.device gets set right away
      setDevice();

}).service('UseHttp', function($http) {....
```

But for some reason when I change my window size to reach a new threshold the this p tag on the view does not update (it does however show the initial 'device')

```
 <article ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl" class="content-wrapper">
     <p>{{myCtrl.device}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the device in the resize event nothing is firing a digest cycle when the model is updated.  You'll need to do it manually with a $scope.$apply() like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   setDevice();
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing the $apply() from within the setDevice() call because that's actually where the scope mutation occurs.

Comment: @YonaAppletree - Problem doing it there is that setDevice() get called initially while a digest is already under way.

Comment: The only problem with this-- on window resize I'm getting the error: 'Can't find variable: $scope'.  I updated my code above to show my full controller. Where do I store the $scope variable?

Comment: You simply need ti inject $scope in your controller, like this .controller('MyController', function(UseHttp, $scope){ ...